# how to change the font in text mode VIM (not gvim with GUI)

Tags: vim, fonts, console

I'd like to change the default font in VIM to Adobe Source Code Pro on a CentOS server (without desktop GUI). I've installed the OTF fonts in the package. How can I have the new monospace font set correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In console mode, Vim is using the current font of your terminal. So you have to find out on your system, how to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in another answer, the choice of font in a terminal application is not chosen by vim, but rather the system settings. Assuming you want to change the font for the entire system's consoles, you can take a look at this link from the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font#Console_fonts). While this is specific to ArchLinux, you will find this article (and most of the articles in that wiki) to be informative and applicable to many flavors of GNU/Linux. If you are trying to change the font used by an X windows terminal application, such as gnome-terminal, sakura, or xterm, you will either need to consult that application's documentation or set the X windows terminal font. [This link](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/fonts/X-Window-System-fonts.html) has some details on accomplishing that.